# Rest Service not seeing parameters from Grails Rest Client Builder

Tags: rest, grails

So I have a simple Grails UI which takes a few fields .. firstName, lastName etc. in a form. The controller calls a service method which then uses the Rest Client Builder plugin to call a REST service.

The rest service is not recognizing the parameters however.

Here is the simple rest call.

```
    def resp = rest.post(baseUrl, params)
            {
                header 'Accept', 'application/json'
                contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
```

Using version 2.0.1 of the plugin.

params looks like

```
[firstName:Kas, action:index, format:null, controller:myController, max:10]
```

Rest Service Method looks like ...

```
@POST
@Path("/employees")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public IdmResult createNewEmployee(@FormParam("firstName") String firstName) {
    try {
        if(firstName == null) return constructFailedIdmResult("First Name is a required field");

        // Do some other stuff
    }
 }
```

Service responds with "First Name is a required field"

When I submit the Post from Postman it works fine. Successful request from Postman looks like

```
POST /idm/employees HTTP/1.1
Host: <ip>:<url>
Accept: application/json 
firstName: Kas
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Would like to figure how I can see the request that the plugin is constructing so I can compare differences, but ultimately I just need to know how to properly send the request from the plugin so that the Rest Service recognizes the form parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rest client should be using request body to POST:

```
def resp = rest.post(baseUrl) {
    header 'Accept', 'application/json'
    contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    json {
        firstName = "Kas"
    }
}
```

or simply,

```
def resp = rest.post(baseUrl) {
    header 'Accept', 'application/json'
    contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    json firstName: "Kas"
}
```

Refer [docs](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-rest-client-builder/) for detail.

**UPDATE:**

Since producer is expecting request params as big query string instead of JSON, you might end up doing this instead:

```
def queryString = params.collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }.join(/&/)

def resp = rest.post("$baseUrl?$queryString") {
    header 'Accept', 'application/json'
    contentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
```

or just `def resp = rest.post("$baseUrl?$queryString")`

Comment: Is there a way to pass the params object in the request body cleanly without specifying each parameter individually?

Comment: you can use `json params`. But why would you pass request elements which is unnecessary for the producer. like `action` and `controller`. They are irrelevant for the producer.

Comment: the form will have many more possible fields other than first name. The update form will have over 20 possible fields that can be updated...also it will be cleaner if the service call does not need to be recoded each time the form fields are changed.

Comment: Well in that case, I would have done a mapping from params to a new map or just remove those unwanted `<k,v>` and send it over. Anyways, using `json params` works?

Comment: First attempt gave same error ... I want to get a look at the actual request ... should make the issue obvious I think ...

Comment: Producer expects a query string for a POST request which is pretty odd.

Comment: Yes, passing it as a query string did it. Thank you. However, is the inability to pass form requests as described in the doc a bug ?

Comment: No. It is the Producer which only accepts `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not a JSON body.

Comment: It is a lot better to use `URLEncodedUtils.format()` to convert params map to query parameters.

Answer (score 2):

To pass the values cleanly in the request body, use a MultiValueMap and the (undocumented, from what I see) 'body()' method as per this answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/21744515/17123