# Grooviest way to send HTTP POST with JSON payload in Grails

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I know how to send an HTTP POST with JSON payload using Apache HTTP library or other conventional java ways. But is there a groovier or in fact *grooviest* way to do so in grails?

I want a simplistic solution with minimum lines of code(=beauty of groovy/grails).

**EDIT**
I don't want to use any third party library. I am looking for a pure grails way to do it. 
Also the http post should be synchronous(blocking) not asynchronous.

Comment: [Rest Client Builder](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/tree/master/grails-datastore-rest-client) has become an integral part of Grails now. Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22415689/rest-service-not-seeing-parameters-from-grails-rest-client-builder) answer for an example usage. This wraps `RestTemplate` provided by Spring with a convenient DSL.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Jodd](http://jodd.org/doc/http.html). E.g.:

```
def response = HttpRequest
        .post('http://srv:8080/api/jsonws/user/get-user-by-id')
        .form('userId', '10194')
        .send()
```

Sending a JSON:

```
def resourcePost = request().
          method(POST.toString()).
          path('http://some.url.com/api').
          body('{"value":1}').
          send()
```

Comment: How do I send a JSON payload with http POST using this library?

Comment: @игор, there's no need to Jodd JSON library - however it's nice - JSON is natively supported in groovy.

Comment: @Opal you are right, just in case if you need some extra features. Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

[HttpBuilder](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder) is expressive and powerful / extensible

```
  new HTTPBuilder(queryUrl).request(Method.POST, ContentType.JSON){
          body = payload
          response.success = { streamResponse, reader ->
               result = reader.readLines().join()
          }
   }
```

Comment: Its great but asynchronous. Duh!

Comment: The example above is blocking. This line forces the wait until it is complete - result = reader.readLines().join(). Do you want synchronous or async?

Comment: Synchronous would be more simple than asynchronous. So looking for synchronous.

Comment: Also is it a standard grails library?