# Fetching data from a microservice to rest in grails

Tags: grails, microservices

I have a rest and a microservice.In microservice i have a table and i want that table data to be fetched to rest and i have written the below way in a rest demoController.

```
def result = restBuilder().post("http://localhost:2222/api/microservice/fetchData"){
            header 'authorization', 'fdgtertddfgfdgfffffff'
            accept("application/json")
            contentType("application/json")
            json "{'empId':1,'ename':'test1'}"
        }
```

But it throws an error "No signature of method: demoController.restBuilder() is applicable for argument types: () values: []".How should i fetch data from a microservice to rest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grails RestBuilder simple POST example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744236/grails-restbuilder-simple-post-example)

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method named `restBuilder()` and that method does not exist.  If you want that to work, you will need to implement that method and have it return something that can deal with a call to `post(String, Closure)`.

You probably are intending to use the `RestBuilder` class.  The particulars will depend on which version of Grails you are using but you probably want is something like this...

```
RestBuilder restBuilder = new RestBuilder()
restBuilder.post('http://localhost:2222/api/microservice/fetchData'){
    header 'authorization', 'fdgtertddfgfdgfffffff'
    accept 'application/json'
    json {
        empId = 1
        name = 'test1'
    }
}
```

You may need to add a dependency on `grails-datastore-rest-client` in your `build.gradle`.

```
compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client"
```

I hope that helps.